# Прилагательные, вставка

Tags: прилагательные

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, на месте () нужно ли ставить запятые/тире? Это же, вроде, вставка? Или нет? Предложение: "Собака () большая, черная () спит".

Answer (score 3):

Лучше поставить запятые: **Собака, большая, черная, спит.**

Обособление определений запятыми  ― это тоже выделение информации, в данном случае вполне достаточное.

Здесь как бы два сообщения: собака спит, собака большая, черная.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!